# jq suppress parsing error for 404 json files

Tags: shell, curl, error-handling, jq

echo $(curl -s -u user:pwd "http://site/file.json" | jq -e -r '.data[]? | select(.state == "Active") | if  . == null then "Installing" elif . == "Active" then "Active" else "Installing" end')

Following is the error:

parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0

In a scenario when file.json doesn't exist 404 page is returned and jq is throwing a parsing error. In such case I want to return string "Installing". Tried many things but nothing is working out, please help.

Comment: what should be printed if `curl` returned an error different from `404` ?

Comment: Expecting "Installing" to be printed for all other errors too. "Active" should be printed only when .data[].state returns "Acitve".

Comment: can you post an expected input json structure?

Answer (score 1):

Write the response into a variable:

```
# -f makes curl return an error in case of HTTP error.
# Check "man curl" on how reliable this is.
response="$(curl -f ...)"
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
    echo "Installing"
else
    jq FILTER <<< "${response}"
fi
```